# Функции PHP не поддерживают русский язык

Tags: json, php, unicode

Юзаю PHP Version 5.2.17 Apache 2.2.21. [Ставил по инструкции](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/apache/Apache2-PHP5-MySql5/). Без MySQL.

Проблема в том, что не работала функция `json_decode` тогда и только тогда, когда в строке JSON были русские символы.

Попытался выкрутиться, после замены их на символы вида `\u****` начало работать, но при попытке автоматизации заметил, что не работает также функция chr для русских (может есть прямая функция, как перегнать строку(символы) в коды unicode?).

Что делать? Обычный вывод русских работает... только с обработкой проблема.

Comment: Что-то страшное вы описываете, конечно, можно придумать какой-то изврат для решения поверхностной проблемы, но ИМХО вам надо смотреть с кодировками... Вообще какая у вас кодировка в `head` и в чем именно выражается то, что не работает `json_decode`?

Comment: json_decode и JSON вообще работает только с UTF-8

Comment: Так же, как и любое обращение к скрипту посредством аякса. Все идет на утф8. Отсюда и пляшите. Если ваш сайт на 1251, то получая запрос, переводите его сразу на 1251 и потом перед отсылкой четко определяйте:

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');

Это для тех у кого с аяксом такие же траблы.

Comment: Пример неработы `json_decode()` и `chr()` в студию, пожалуйста. Какой код выполняете, какой результат получаете.

Comment: <small><b>оффтоп</b> независимо от того как решится этот вопрос - мораль сей басни такова - UTF-8 всему голова xD</small>

Answer (score 2):

JSON - формат, поддерживающий исключительно UTF-8. Рекомендую перевести все в utf-8, в том числе и кодировку самих скриптов. Проблем сразу станет меньше. Главное не забывать, что со строками в utf надо работать функциями с префиксом mb_